# APACHE SSL WWW redirect to real name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

In .htaccess file:

```
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite file name
RewriteRule ^dome.htm$ dome.php [L,QSA]


# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Forced SSL & WWW works good except rewrite filename where request made from below URL it return to real file name which `https://www.example.com/dome.php`:

```
example.com/dome.htm
www.example.com/dome.htm
https://example.com/home.htm
```

How to keep `https://www.example.com/dome.htm` when access above URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of processing:

```
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Rewrite file name
RewriteRule ^dome\.htm$ dome.php [L,QSA]
```

Also note the slightly modified regular expression in that `RewriteRule` ;-)

Why does this make a difference? Imagine an incoming request getting rewritten... With your order of rules the request *first* gets rewritten to `/dome.php`, *then* redirected to `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`, which will instruct the browser to load `/dome.php` from that new URL... RewriteRules are processed from top to bottom. Sure, you specified the `[L]` flag, however that only ends the rewriting _for that iteration! If the last iteration changed the request (a rewriting was performed), then *another* iteration is done by the http server.

An alternative would be to leave your order of rules but use the `[END]` flag instead of `[L]` which does what you want. But it is only supported on newer versions of the apache http server, from version 2.4 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
RewriteRule    ^dome.htm?$    dome.php [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "dome"
```